# I am using @material-ui/icons in a new project but getting issue with the library files

Tags: react-native, material-ui, icons, react-native-cli, material-icons

So I have installed @material-ui/icons library along with npm install @mui/material library as suggested. but my issue is when I am importing any icons from the website and implementing it in my app.js return statement I'm getting this error log.

> Invariant Violation: View config getter callback for component `style` must be a function (received `undefined`). Make sure to start component names with a capital letter.

This error is located at:
in style (created by Insertion)
in Insertion (created by MuiSvgIconRoot)
in MuiSvgIconRoot
in SvgIcon
in CancelIcon
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by App)
in App
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by AppContainer)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by AppContainer)
in AppContainer
in MaterialIconDemo(RootComponent), js engine: hermes
ERROR  Invariant Violation: View config getter callback for component `path` must be a function (received `undefined`). Make sure to start component names with a capital letter.

This error is located at:
in path
in svg (created by MuiSvgIconRoot)
in MuiSvgIconRoot
in SvgIcon
in CancelIcon
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by App)
in App
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by AppContainer)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by AppContainer)
in AppContainer
in MaterialIconDemo(RootComponent), js engine: hermes
ERROR  Invariant Violation: View config getter callback for component `style` must be a function (received `undefined`). Make sure to start component names with a capital letter.

This error is located at:
in style (created by Insertion)
in Insertion (created by MuiSvgIconRoot)
in MuiSvgIconRoot
in SvgIcon
in CancelIcon
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by App)
in App
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by AppContainer)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by AppContainer)
in AppContainer
in MaterialIconDemo(RootComponent), js engine: hermes

I want to know what I'm doing is wrong while installing or importing the library.

I tired the installation guide as well as searching solutions but there are no solutions for this particular library which I was able to find.

I know about vector-icons library and I have used it in my previous projects but I want to use this particular library.

Comment: if you have mui 5 then try this `npm install @mui/icons-material`

Comment: @Usama I am using the same library.  and this are my libraries version

"@mui/icons-material": "^5.11.9",
    "@mui/material": "^5.11.9",

Comment: @FaizKhan Hi, were you able to fix this in the end? I'm having trouble with the same error atm

Comment: @JasperMW Hey, sorry for the late reply but now i wasn't able to solve the issue as I think react native is not supporting the mui library.